# menu for changing basemap in ArcGIS API 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Is there a way to create a drop down menu for changing the basemap in ArcGIS api 4.x similar to the one here https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_agol I have a working version of it in 3.x but am hoping to upgrade to 4.x. I found a similar example for changing the basemap here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-basemapgallery/index.html but am having trouble implementing a drop down menu version

I found a tutorial for creating a menu (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/DropDownMenu.html) but am having trouble implementing the basemap change portion

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the basemap change you just need to change the Map's basemap property. So if a user selects "satellite" from the dropdown you would just need to modify the property with the new value.

```
    var basemapDropdown = document.getElementById("basemap-select");
    basemapDropdown.addEventListener("change", changeBasemap);

    function changeBasemap(event){
      var newBasemap = basemapDropdown.value;
      view.map.basemap = newBasemap;
    }
```

See example I created her: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoyZaJ

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can Use BaseMap Gallery

```
toggleGallery() {
    
    
    if(this._view.ui.find("basemapGallery")){
      this._view.ui.remove("basemapGallery")
      return;
    }

    const basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
      view: this._view,
      container: "basemapGalleryDiv",
      id:"basemapGallery"
    });
    
    // Add the widget to the top-right corner of the view
    this._view.ui.add(basemapGallery, {
      position: "top-right"
    });
  }
```

and for Html use

```
<div  id="basemapGalleryDiv"></div>
```

[Base Map Gallery View View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emb5f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
basemapGallery.watch('activeBasemap', function(newValue, oldValue, property, object) {

    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(oldValue);

});
```